# When was the first Mikva built in the USA?

Tags: history, mikvah-ritual-bath, chutz-laaretz

When was the first Mikva built in the USA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if this is the first one, but:

> In the earliest days, the women of
>   Shearith Israel made use of a natural
>   spring near the synagogue for these
>   ritual purposes. By 1759 Shearith
>   Israel built a mikvah on its grounds,
>   adjacent to the Mill Street synagogue.

(http://thehistorybox.com/ny_city/nycity_jewish_family_home_pt_II_article1298.htm)